# OpenJPA timestamp does not store time in DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, openjpa

I am using openjpa with oracle sql developer. In one of the table i have audit fields for storing the timestamp of when the row gets created and the subsequent updated time. Here are the things i tried:

1. Mark the column default as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and using insertable as false in the model. This created the timestamp while row is inserted but while updating it updates the time to all 0 values with the date value remains unchanged.
2. Using @Temporal annotation for timestamp and the type is java.util.Date. This stored only date and no timestamp. Changed the column data type to timestamp and it stores all 0 values in timestamp with current date: 02-MAY-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM
3. I removed the @Temporal and changed the type in my model to java.sql.timestamp. Behaves the same way as above.

Model:

```
@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE_DATE", nullable = false)
private Timestamp lastUpdateDate;

public Timestamp getLastUpdateDate() {
    return this.lastUpdateDate;
}

public void setLastUpdateDate(Timestamp lastUpdateDate) {
    this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
}
```

The value i am setting during creation is :

this.setLastUpdateDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

I searched for the same and tried all the suggestions but somehow its not working for me. The datatype in the db is Timestamp.

Anyone worked with openjpa and faced the same issue? Any idea to resolve this except converting the data type to String or long in the db and store the value accordingly.

Comment: I tried with the listener PrePersist & PreUpdate but the time portion of the field is not getting updated and still showing 0 in the database. Any help at this point would be useful..people using openjpa.